# NSMutableString stringWithString giving crash

Tags: iphone, nsmutablestring

```
ten.textValue = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
ten.textValue = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
```

I am getting crash at second line.
`ten.textValue is NSMutableString`.

Comment: Why do you allocate a brand-new `NSMutableString` only to overwrite it on the next line?

Comment: Commenting it also is giving me a crash.

Comment: Are the 'ten' and 'textField' objects allocated or setup right through IB?

Comment: you can just use ten.textValue =textField.text;

Comment: What crash? You need to give a bit more detail in your questions than just saying "help, it crashes".

Comment: Unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your `ten.textValue = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];` you are creating an object that you own.

When you try to add a string to it in the next line, you are creating an autoreleased string. This is confusing the compiler, which is reporting "hang on - this is an allocated, owned object already".

Instead:

```
if(ten.textValue)
{
    ten.textValue = [NSMutableString stringWithString: textField.text]};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because the `text` property of `UITextField` [is `nil` by default](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html), and passing `nil` to `[NSMutableString stringWithString:nil]` causes a crash.

You need to make sure the `text` is not `nil` when you pass it to be copied, for example like this:

```
[NSMutableString stringWithString: textField.text ? textField.text : @""]
```

You should also eliminate the first line - it serves no purpose, because the allocated and assigned value gets overwritten immediately.

Comment: No. textfield text is not nil because above code is in textFieldShouldReturn. I am getting textfield text.

Comment: @Nitish Did you try changing the second line? Do you still get the crash?